# How to get MethodInfo of static method with generic parameters when method ambiguity occurs?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reactive

The method I would like to obtain is Observable.Return from **System.Reactive**.

It's defined like this:

```cs
public static IObservable<TResult> Return<TResult>(TResult value)
{
    ...
}
```

I've tried with

```cs
Type observableType = typeof(Observable);
MethodInfo returnMethodInfo = observableType.GetMethod("Return");
var genericMethodInfo = returnMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error message:

> Ambiguous match found.

I guess it's because there is another method called "Return":

```cs
public static IObservable<TResult> Return<TResult>(TResult value, IScheduler scheduler)
{
   ...
}
```

How should I call `GetMethod` to get a `MethodInfo` to the method I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it with this solution.

```
    var method = typeof(Observable).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(
            x => x.Name.Equals("Return", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                x.IsGenericMethod && x.GetParameters().Length == 1)
        ?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `GetMethods()` and filter to the one you want; this *could* be as simple as:

```cs
var returnMethodInfo = observableType.GetMethods().Single(x => x.Name == "Return"
    && x.IsGenericMethodDefinition && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);
```